# SAS literal column names are not valid while executing a sas script through excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I am trying to run a perfectly executable `SAS` script through excel VBA, but it's throwing the error:

> "SAS variable name e.g. '2018'n is not valid"

I am aware that SAS variables should not start with a numeric value, but I am feeding it as SAS literal using 'var-name'n, and it is perfectly running in SAS environment using EG 9.2. Therefore it should ideally run in VBA too as VBA is also running the script in a SAS environment.

I can resolve this issue by renaming the variable, but I just want to know the exact reason why it's giving an error in VBA.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Mohit

Comment: Show the VBA code you are using to run the SAS code.  Is the EG profile connecting to local or remote SAS server ?

Comment: Show the value of the VALIDVARNAME option in both sessions.  You can use PROC OPTIONS or the GETOPTION() function to see the current setting..

Answer (score 0):

Variable names that start with a number are not valid unless you have set the VALIDVARNAME option to ANY.